# How to insert image in the textbox on the right side in XUL?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I'm able to add the image icon inside the textbox XUL element in my firefox addon, but this icon is appearing in the left side of textbox and I'm unable to a align the icon on the right side.

Here is the code:

```
<textbox>
    <image src="chrome://myextension/skin/icon.png"/>           
</textbox>
```

I tried to put the image in the hbox and applied align=right but no success. But I'm sure this is possible for eg urlbar-icons and searchbar-icons but I don't know how to implement this is normal textbox. Please tell me how to do so?

Comment: Add `img`instead of image and use the `align` attribute. Check here, <https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/align>

Comment: tried this but it's still showing up on the left side

`<img xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" align="end" src="chrome://ext/skin/icon.png"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at it using [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) you will see some anonymous content being generated for the `<textbox>` tag (the actual input field) and your image being inserted before it. You cannot change the insertion point. However, you can use [`-moz-box-ordinal-group` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-box-ordinal-group) to make your image be displayed after the input field (which has the default `-moz-box-ordinal-group: 1` value):

```xml
<textbox>
    <image src="..." style="-moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;"/>
</textbox>
```

Note that `-moz-box-ordinal-group` will be renamed into `box-ordinal-group` once the [corresponding standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) becomes more mature.

Comment: Thanks Wladimir. Actually I solved the problem by appending new image element in textbox by getAnonymousElementByAttribute in my Javascript code but the solution you provided is way better :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the align=end attribute on textbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/align